# Getting an empty list when scraping with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to create a python function that can scrape the article titles of a search result on Popular Science's website.

I have written this code, which has worked for a similar science-related website but when I run it specifically for Popular Science, it returns an empty list.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

def scraper(text):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
    wired_dict = []
    driver.get("https://www.popsci.com/search-results/" + text + "/")
    search = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("siq-partner-result")
    for words in search:
        wired_dict.append(words.text)
    return wired_dict

print(scraper("science"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` for wait while page is loaded.

```
from selenium import webdriver


def scrapper(text):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
    driver.get(f"https://www.popsci.com/search-results/{text}/")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    search = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("siq-partner-result")
    wired_dict = [word.text for word in search]

    print(wired_dict)


scrapper('sample')
```

Comment: Thank you soooooooooooooo much!

Answer (score 0):

This page takes a while to load.  You are using `driver.find_elements_by_class_name` before the page has finished loading, so it's not finding those elements.

You can test this theory by `import time` and `time.sleep(5)` just before the search code.

The best solution is to keep checking until the elements are loaded with `WebDriverWait()` wait until the elements have loaded.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


def scraper(text):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
    wired_dict = []
    driver.get("https://www.popsci.com/search-results/" + text + "/")
    delay = 3
    WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'siq-partner-result')))

    search = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("siq-partner-result")
    for words in search:
        wired_dict.append(words.text)
    return wired_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebDriverWait for the desired element to visible and then try to find the elements.

Using XPATH :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='siq-partner-result']")))
search = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("siq-partner-result")
```

Note : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```